# Request for reference books, articles, papers on the topic topic of Non Abelian Kummer Extensions.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, galois-extensions, class-field-theory

I am a final year undergraduate student. I am doing my research on Non-Abelian Kummer Extensions. Can someone please introduce me to formal definition of Non-abelian Kummer Extensions. I know it is some type of Galois extension but I don't how to define it. Is it just a non abelian Galois extension or does non Abelian Galois extensions need some requirements to become non Abelian Kummer Extensions. Please help me in this regard. I am following the book "Algebra" by Serge Lang. Can someone refer me some other literature on this topic. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, so I was surprised to hear that non-abelian Kummer extensions are a thing. [Encyclopedia](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Kummer_extension) mentions an article of Takahashi from 1968, but it is clear that the encyclopedia article is insufficient for your purposes.